# Algorithm to calculate if 'n' or more intervals intersect & the total of the respective intersections

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, math, intervals

I need help developing a weird algorithm.  I have a JavaScript object containing people and an array for each person of start and end time intervals in milliseconds:

```
var person = [
    (1533242595, 1533242999),
    (1533242595, 1533242999),
    (1533242595, 1533242999)
]
```

I need to determine if any intervals intersect/overlap, but for *n* or more intersections (for example, determining if 4+ intervals overlap) and calculate the total sum of the *n* or more intersecting intervals.

A function that takes a `n` parameter and the `person` object would be perfect.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @chevybow Honestly I don't know where to start.  I've been staring at this for a while and can't figure it out.

Comment: first, establish the conditions of intersect/overlap. then loop over list and compare first interval with all intervals and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First the person must be defined as list of lists:

```
var person = [
    [1533242595, 1533242999],
    [1533242595, 1533242999],
    [1533242595, 1533242999]
];
```

Here you can find a sample of function:

```
function limit_intersection(limit, person) {
  var arrayLength = person.length;
  var intersections = 0;
  var intersectionsum = 0;
  var min, max = 0;
  var tmp;
  var intervals = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength-1; i++) {
    if(person[i][0] > person[i][1]) {
        tmp = person[i][1];
      person[i][1] = person[i][0];
      person[i][0] = tmp;
    }
    for (var j = i+1; j < arrayLength; j++) {
        if(person[j][0] > person[j][1]) {
        tmp = person[j][1];
        person[j][1] = person[j][0];
        person[j][0] = tmp;
      }

        min = 0;
      max = 0;
        if(person[i][1] <=  person[j][0] || person[i][0] >= person[j][1]){
        // no intersection
        continue;
      }
        intersections +=1;
        if(person[i][0] >= person[j][0]) {
            min = person[i][0]; 
        } else {
            min = person[j][0];
        }

        if(person[i][1] >= person[j][1]) {
            max = person[j][1]; 
        } else {
            max = person[i][1];
        }
        intervals.push([min,max]);
        intersectionsum += max-min;

    }
    }
  return {'n' : intersections, 'sum' : intersectionsum, 'intervals' : intervals};
}
```

An here the working demo on [jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/0gx36wjf/40/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that's how your data is structured? Because that does not look like a [Javascript object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to me, correct me if I'm wrong.

Break your code in to bite sized problems. What is an overlap? How do we check if two intervals overlap each other? When you make that function, use that to loop through your person intervals. Make a variable that contains the sum of the matches and return that.

```
function overlaps(startX, endX, startY, endY) {
    if(endX < startY || endY < startX) return false;
  return true;
}

console.log(overlaps(1,2,1,4)) // true
console.log(overlaps(10,20,1,11)) // true

console.log(overlaps(1,2,3,4)) // false
console.log(overlaps(4,3,2,1)) // false
```

Now find a way to loop over your persons checking for overlaps with this bite sized function.

**Edited**, here's an example of answer with bite-sized readable functions instead of the spagetti code in the selected answer:

```js
// Check if two intervals overlap
function overlaps(startX, endX, startY, endY) {
  if(endX < startY || endY < startX) return false;
  return true;
}

// Check how many times two person arrays overlap
function comparePersons(person1, person2){
  var matches = 0;
  person1.forEach(function(elementX) {
    person2.forEach(function(elementY) {
      if(overlaps(
      elementX[0],elementX[1],
      elementY[0],elementY[1]
      )) matches +=1
    });
  });
  return matches;
}

// Check how many times all persons overlap with another
function compareAll(persons, n){
    var totalMatches = 0;
    persons.forEach(function(element, index1) {
     var compareMatches = 0;
      persons.forEach(function(compareElement, index2) {
          if(index1 !== index2) {
          compareMatches += comparePersons(element, compareElement)
        }
     });
      if(compareMatches >= n) totalMatches += 1;
   });
  return totalMatches;
}

// Create persons to test
var person1 = [
  [10,20],
  [100,200]
]

var person2 = [
  [1,2000],
  [50,1000]
]

var person3 = [
  [10,200],
  [0,1],
  [1000,2000],
  [100,2000]
]

// Create one array with all persons
var allPersons = [
    person1, person2, person3
]

// Test by console logging
console.log(compareAll(allPersons, 5));
```

Comment: take a look on the requested result: `I need to determine if any intervals intersect/overlap, but for n or more intersections (for example, determining if 4+ intervals overlap) and calculate the total sum of the n or more intersecting intervals.`

Comment: @vasilenicusor thanks for the note, edited to match the req result https://jsfiddle.net/u09sbkoq/98/